# mysql table selection not listing logically

Tags: mysql, date

I have wrote the following query that would attempt to select all events where start date is anything from current date (I have start_date and end_date fields in table):

```
$query = "SELECT id,title,start_date 
          FROM events 
          WHERE start_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND city = '$cityName' 
          ORDER BY start_date DESC";
```

The only problem with the above code as I came to realize was that if an event started lets say 3 months before `NOW()` then it would not display. I went and tried to re-write it, but it didn't work. this is what I managed:

```
"SELECT id,title,start_date 
 FROM events 
 WHERE start_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY || start_date <= NOW() && end_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY";
```

What I tried to do is to select all events where start date is greater than or equal current date (`NOW()`) or even select events with start_date that may be less than current date yet the end date is after `NOW()`. Any suggestions on how this should be fixed? I want it to show all events as long as they have not already come to pass (of course that means end date is not less than current real date).

Thanks,

EDIT:

```
$query = "SELECT id,title,start_date FROM events WHERE start_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND city = '$cityName' ORDER BY start_date DESC";

$query_posted = "SELECT id,title,start_date FROM events WHERE start_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND city = '$cityName' AND category = '$tag' ORDER BY start_date DESC";
```

the first one loaded the events after I modified it (modification not included) but second one failed and i think it is due to another two AND's at the end.

Comment: `of course that means end date is not less than current real date` Wouldn't that mean that you need `WHERE end_date >= now()`?

Comment: @lanzz: Why don't you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your are requesting if it were run this moment.

```
WHERE start_date >= 2012-08-03 || start_date <= 2012-09-02 && end_date >= 2012-08-03
```

In order for this to work, you need to use parentheses to separate the comparisons.

```
WHERE start_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY || (start_date <= NOW() && end_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `BETWEEN` operator:

```
WHERE start_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
    AND end_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Lastly, you mention that you want the `end_date` to be greater than `NOW()`. So just drop the `- INTERVAL 30 DAY` to get:

```
WHERE start_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() AND end_date >= NOW()
```

Comment: I tried the last one without interval and it didn't work. The question edited to add another part of code that may have rendered your code malfunctional